# Does Datamapper for Codeigniter force an intermediate table for all relationships?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I'm moving towards an ORM for my codeigniter application and have chosen [datamapper](http://stensi.com/datamaper). However, in the [rules](http://stensi.com/datamapper/pages/database.html) section, it states the following:

> A joining table must exist between
>   each related normal tables, regardless
>   of the type of relationship.

I have dozens of tables that are in a one->many relationship. Does this mean that I have to create intermediate (joining) tables between each of them as if they were many-many?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, actually, the model that has a `$has_one` relationship set will have a field ending in `_id,` which refers to the object with the `$has_many` relationship set.

So, for example:

```
class Recipe extends DataMapper {
    var $has_many = array('product', 'rating', 'recipe_category');
    var $has_one = array('recipe_source', 'user');
    (...)
}

class Recipe_Source extends DataMapper {
    var $has_many = array('recipe');
    (...)
}
```

In this case, DataMapper made a table `recipes` with a `recipe_source_id` column, and a `recipe_sources` table that required no extra fields.

Now, for many-to-many relationships, a join table will be created, and it follows a strict convention.

The join table name will be the two plurals of the joined models, separated by an underscore, in alphabetical order.

So, using this model:

```
class Product extends DataMapper {
    var $has_one = array('cheese_style', 'butter_style', 'cheese_flavor');
    var $has_many = array('product_size', 'recipe');
    (...)
}
```

Now, I end up with a join table in my database called `products_recipes.`

This is how it is handled by the DMZ DataMapper library (http://www.overzealous.com/dmz/), which is supposed to be a drop-in replacement for the old stensi DataMapper library, so I'm going to assume the conventions are the same.

Even so, I highly recommend making the switch to DMZ.

Answer (score 1):

The doc nevers says explicitly in one place what you should do to avoid using a joining table for something as simple as a one-to-many relationship. You collect the pieces of information around (Database Tables, Setting up Relationships, Advanced Relationships) and understand that it is possible without being shown how-to.

**Just create the foreign key** in the child table using the "_id" suffix convention and Datamapper shall recognize it **automatically** (at least that is how it worked out for me), assuming that you set up the has_one and has_many attributes in the two models. As **country_id** in this example:

```
// class User extends DataMapper { var $has_one = array('country'); ... }
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `country_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `confirm_password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

// class Country extends DataMapper { var $has_many = array('user'); ... }
CREATE TABLE `countries` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortunately, it does mean that. This is one of the reasons why I had to change my DB design

Comment: No it doesn't.  Only if you have a many to many join.  Read the docs.